# ¿Cómo recibir datos JSON desde mi propio servidor en Localhost?

Tags: json, reactjs, php7, pdo

Estoy haciendo una app de prueba con ReactJS, y todo ha funcionado hasta ahora.
El funcionamiento de mi app es el de registrar tareas, borrarlas y marcarlas como realizadas.
Para probar su funcionamiento, en principio utilicé un archivo .json que yo mismo codifiqué para tener datos de prueba, pero ya que logré avanzar en el lenguaje, ya es hora de poder realizar consultas a tablas de BBDD.
Tengo mi código PHP completo. Creé una tabla con unos datos para las tareas y, a la vez, realicé la consulta y recibí los resultados en un controlador el cual me imprime un string json al pasar los resultados de la consulta guardados en un arreglo y utilizar sobre el mismo la función `json_encode()`.
Estos resultados se imprimen perfectamente ya que he revisado el código PHP en un proyecto aparte para verificar su funcionalidad, y el resultado fue exitoso. El problema está, según pienso, en la consulta fetch que realizo en mi código JS.
Les adjunto el código y espero puedan ayudarme.
De antemano gracias.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TaskForm from './components/TaskForm';
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";

class App extends Component {

  state = {

    tasks: []

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch("./php/controlador/controlGetTasks.php")
      .then(res => JSON.parse(res))
      .then(res => console.log(typeof(res)))
      .then(

        (result) => {

          this.setState({

            tasks: result

          });

        },
        (error) => {

          this.setState({

            error

          });

        }

      )

  }

  newTask = (title, description) => {

    const newTask = {

      title: title,
      description: description,
      done: false,
      id: this.state.tasks.length

    }

    this.setState({

      tasks: [...this.state.tasks, newTask] //Tomo todo lo que ya estaba en el estado y le agrego la nueva tarea

    })

  }

  deleteTask = (id) => {

    const tasks = this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id);
    this.setState({

      tasks: tasks

    });

  }

  done = (id) => {

    const tasks = this.state.tasks.map(task => {

      if (task.id === id){

        task.done = !task.done; //Ve el estado de 'done' y con el signo ! se cambia al estado contrario

      }
      
      return task;

    });

    this.setState({

      tasks: tasks

    })

  }

  render() {

    const { error, tasks } = this.state;
    if (error){

      return <div>Error: { error.message } { tasks }</div>

    } else {

      return (

        <div>
    
          <h1>Tasks List</h1>
    
          <Tasks tasks={ this.state.tasks } deleteTask={ this.deleteTask } done={ this.done } />
  
          <h3>Add a Task</h3>
  
          <TaskForm newTask={ this.newTask } />
    
        </div>
    
      )  

    }

  }

}

export default App;
```

```
<?php

require_once('../modelo/conexion.php');
require_once('../modelo/consultas.php');
require_once('../modelo/constantes.php');

$consulta = new Consultas();
$rows = $consulta -> getTasks();

if(is_array($rows) || is_object($rows) && strlen($rows) > 0){

   $json = array();

   foreach($rows as $row){

    $json[] = array(

        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'description' => $row['description'],
        'done' => $row['done'],

      );

   }

$jsonString = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonString;

} else {

   echo 'No hay nada que devolver';
   die();

}

?>
```

Comment: "El problema está, según pienso, en la consulta fetch" que problema?

Comment: Me sale este error al ingresar a mi index de la aplicación: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Intenta quitar el `JSON.parse` porque estas usando el `json_encode()`

Comment: Es decir, pienso que el error está en la ruta que coloco dentro de la función fetch. La carpeta donde tengo guardado el código PHP se encuentra en la carpeta src de mi proyecto ReactJS, entonces no sé si el problema es al tratar de ingresar en esa carpeta, que leí por foros que el problema puede darse al no encontrarse el archivo solicitado.

Comment: Probastes quitar el `JSON.parse`?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Ahora me sale esto.

Comment: Tengo dos inquietudes: 1. tienes múltiples .then() en secuencia, considerando que son controladores asíncronos, ¿cabe esperar que del segundo en adelante se disparen? No sería mejor reunirlos en un sólo proceso, pues no veo qué debe esperarse del segundo en adelante. 2. El php en controlGetTasks.php debiera terminar con exit() es lo típico para hacer devoluciones ajax. Y, no lo hace. ¿No es necesario? Es posible que te haga falta. **Estas inquietudes de originan en mi ignorancia** nunca he usado secuencias de .then() y siempre cierro mis scripts de respuesta a llamados ajax con exit().

Comment: Voy a probar con el exit(). Las llamadas a .then() eran para ayudarme a ver la raíz del problema y poder imprimir por consola lo que traía el json.